# How to print the exceptional path by using grape API framework in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using grape in rails, after mount all API routes, I put this code to catch exceptional routes for error handling. My problem is how can I print the path? like "Path[#{path}] 404 Not Found", I am not sure I can use the parameter *any* or *'*path'*.

```
route :any, '*path' do
  error!("404 Not Found", 404)
end
```

Comment: Can you call `route_path` inside it ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh No, `route_path` can not be accessed inside it.